# Using emsserver/emsserver.dll in URL of API Call in Production Environment

Tags: iis, ems, rad-studio

I have created an application that utilizes RAD Studio's EMS Server functionality. The development has been completed and tested in a production environment. The EMS Server documentation shows that in order to make an API call the emsserver.dll needs to be included in the URL.

https://{hostname}/emsserver/emserver.dll/API/Login?token={TokenValue}

Most APIs I have encountered do not have the dll embedded into the URL.

https://{hostname}/API/Login?token={TokenValue}

This is not a big deal as the API call works fine as is. I was just wondering if there is property or setting I can use in RAD Server or IIS in order to default the emsserver/emsserver.dll portion of the URL.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thanks Lex, I did a quick review of the document and it looks like it is exactly what I need. I will confirm once I have had a chance to try to add a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to redirect or rewrite the url from `https://{hostname}/API/Login?token={TokenValue}` to `https://{hostname}/emsserver/emserver.dll/API/Login?token={TokenValue}` in IIS?

If this is your reuqimrent, I suggest you could try to use url rewrite extension to achieve your reuqirement.

You could install it from this url and add below [url](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) rewrite rule into your web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>

<rewrite>
<rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to dll">
                    <match url="API/Login" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{hostname}/emsserver/emserver.dll/API/Login" />
                </rule>

</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks Brando. I quickly reviewed the document identified by Lex and it appears that I may want to Rewrite the URL as you suggested. I've just been pulled onto a priority task. As soon as I get a chance, I will  give it it a try.

Comment: Thanks Brando and @Lex. After downloading the URL Rewrite Extension I applied a rule very similar to Brando's only I used a regular expression to capture the entire API call    <match url="^API/([_0-9a-z-/]+)" /> <action type="Rewrite" url="EMSServer/EMSServer.dll/API/{R:1}" />